# How are moderators doing, what can we do different or better?

Tags: discussion, moderators

What does the community thinks of moderation so far: what do you like or dislike of what you see mods doing on the site, what should we emphasize, improve, or implement to make the experience better?

---

Note: this was first posted during the summer 2022 election cycle to encourage participation (more candidates). It is retained to obtain ongoing feedback into what mods might do/change.

Answer (score -4):

> "How are moderators doing, what can we do different or better?"

- [Melanie](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/402/melanie-shebel) could do better by [participating more](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/402/melanie-shebel?tab=activity).
- [Loong](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/103369/loong) (before losing the diamond in 2020) could have done better by getting into fewer conflicts with users, and not (in my opinion) abusing diamond mod powers awarded in a Chem election when interacting with users in the Physics.SE chat rooms (when multiple Physics diamond mods were there at the time and didn't take the same course of action).
- [Todd](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/4?tab=nomination#post-149535) (before resigning in 2022) could do better by getting into fewer conflicts with users.

If I may, rather than only commenting on what diamond mods can do "different" or "better", I'd like to comment on one of the things that I like very much about [Martin](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/4945/martin-%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%B3). Martin has frequently been available in chat. It seems to me like if Martin and I got into a conflict we'd be able to work it out in a civil way. The channel seems to be open for discussion. I also feel like I've managed to connect with Martin on a more "personal" level rather than strictly in a moderator-user relationship. In 2018 when I proposed the "Scientific Software Stack Exchange" I tried to get in touch with all Chem.SE diamond mods, but **only Martin replied to me** in chat. Again in 2019 when I proposed [MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/), Martin was the only elected Chem.SE mod to converse with me about it (then later was the only one to help that site during the Private Beta stage).

Also, I think Buck Thorn, andselisk and orthocresol (along with Martin, who I've already mentioned positively) have been doing a good job, and are visibly very active. They all seem approachable, and I feel like I could talk to them in chat if I **really** needed to for some reason. Some former and present diamond mods here and elsewhere are less accessible, and I feel as if there's no channel open to communicate with them if I have a concern (which would mean my only recourse would be to contact the CMs through the "contact us" form, or to try to get in touch with a different diamond mod about the issue, or to comment on one of their posts to ping them; but none of these options are even close to ideal).

Comment: I'll work on this. I've mostly been focusing on post edits but I can review more. :)

Comment: Before this August 2022 post, [your last post edit](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/402/melanie-shebel?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=2) was in Jun 2022, and there was also zero post edits in January, February, March and April 2022, and in July, August, September, October, and November 2021, etc. I wanted to end this comment with something like "but it's great that you've started to contribute a lot of edits recently!" but after looking at your edits of the last 8 hours, they all seem to be [extremely minor](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/951/54253). I'm just

Comment: [cot'd] trying my best to answer the question of what mods can do better, and more participation all around is just my suggestion :)

Comment: Please do take a look at past meta posts across the network to better understand why these seemingly “extremely minor” edits are made and also encouraged.